# Which graphics adapters outputted S-Video over VGA?

Tags: vga, s-video

To this day you can buy passive cables which separate out S-Video and composite signals from VGA. There's always a warning to check whether your graphics adapter output these over the VGA connector. While I have seen a number of video cards which had a separate S-Video connector, up to the ATI HD 3650 and the Geforce 6200 but I have never in my life seen or heard of a card which outputted S-Video over VGA. Anyone...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some Matrox cards output composite and S-Video using the HD15 port; for example, the [G450 PCI](https://web.archive.org/web/20171220085221/www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/graphics_cards/g_series/g450pci/) (see the TV output chapter in [its manual](https://www.matrox.com/graphics/media/pdf/products/graphics_cards/g_series/en_millg450.pdf)). The adapter cable was optional though and isn’t commonly included with the graphics adapter.

Comment: I'll be damned, you are right. I thought of something much more obscure, maybe some ATI All In Wonder card. Cable: http://www.cablesonline.com/svidrcavidou.html Pinout: https://allpinouts.org/pinouts/cables/audio_video/matrox-g450-and-g550-tv-out-to-s-video-adapter/

Comment: Yes, I thought of the AIWs as well, but I think they had separate ports for composite and S-Video, sometimes with break-out cables, but not combined with the VGA port (although [this](https://allpinouts.org/pinouts/cables/audio_video/ati-radeon-vga-to-tv-cable-schematic/) suggests I’m wrong about that).

Comment: @StephenKitt That diagram you linked seems to be connecting a CGA digital DE-9 connector to the analogue RGB pins of a SCART connector. I'm not sure that would actually work, but it's not an example of VGA port outputting a composite or S-Video signal.

Comment: @Ross the diagram is wrong, look at the list of pins. There never were Radeon cards with CGA-style connectors.

Comment: @StephenKitt Even if it's supposed to be a VGA DE-15 connector. it would be an example of a VGA port outputting RGB with a PAL (maybe NTSC) compatible composite sync, not composite video or S-Video.

Comment: Online PDF, see chapter about TV output:  https://www.matrox.com/graphics/media/pdf/products/graphics_cards/g_series/en_millg450.pdf